# How to audit entire database using node.js?

Tags: node.js, audit

Does anyone know how to audit all the tables in a database.

I need to audit the inserted row & deleted row & updated row

if I change first_name (column) 
it should show the tablename,column name,old value,new value in audit table.

I need procedure for entire database auditing in node.js.

how could you update the table name as 'employee' in audit table?

Could anyone?